# UUDI/GUID primary key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, primary-key, uuid, guid

We have an app (IONIC 2 phone app front-end, ASP .Net Core 2.0 Web Api backend with MySql Server).

The phone app needs to be able to work in offline mode, and be able to sync (up and down) when it has internet connection. I immediately realized the auto-incrementing int primary keys in the MySql database would be an issue, and thought about using GUID/UUID primary keys instead. But I am worried about performance. I have two questions:

1. What is the best way to store a UUID field in MySql? CHAR(36)? As far as I can see, MySql doesn't have a dedicated UUID data type? (I am using MySql Server 5.6.30)
2. Would it be a good idea to NOT make it a Primary Key, so that it's not UNIQUE? Surely this would speed up performance? And a UUID is almost guaranteed to be unique anyway, so there's no need for MySql Server to waste time checking for this...

Thanks

Comment: I don't follow the problem or why you have come down to a choice between UUID or an auto increment primary key.  What would be the issue with just allowing MySQL to assign an id when the app finally gets online and does a sync?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Tim. Well, the phone apps will have a local database where they will store all data while working in offline mode. If we are using an auto-incrementing int primary key, and the user of the phone app creates a new record, it might get ID = 157 (and this will be used in all other tables that have a foreign key to this table). Now, when the phone is online and the app syncs, on the live database it might get a different ID (because other users have synced their new records in the meantime). Now there is a mismatch between the IDs on the phone's db and on the live db

Comment: Yes, when the phone app syncs, the Web API could tell the phone app what the ACTUAL id's are, and the phone app could then update it's ID in all it's tables. But this could be an issue of the Web API tell the phone app "right, the actual ID for that record is 160", but the phone app already has that ID in use (because they guy added 4 new records while working offline)

Comment: I guess I don't see the issue of having two IDs.  The master database uses auto increment, and each app has its own ID.  Nothing wrong with this from the point of view of other apps; those other apps cannot see the new item in the master catalog anyway.

Comment: hmmm.... ok, so there would be some sort of mapping between the client id's and the master id's?

Comment: I mean, if the app does a sync, and the web api tell it "record 160 has changed - here is the updated record". Now, that record on the app is ID 157. How does the app know that record 160 on the master database is actually record 157 on its local database?

Comment: Why do you need a client ID in the first place?  Maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: Well, when the phone app is working in offline mode, it will be storing all data locally on the phone, in an SQLite database, basically mirroring the master MySQL database structure. When tables need to link to other tables (foreign keys, etc.) then this is done via the primary keys. If I undetstood your question correctly? So my concern is that these primary keys on the phone app's database will differ to the ones on the live database (if we use auto-incrementing int's). I thought using UUID's would solve this problem? Unless, we have some sort of mapping between the IDs in the two databases?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I caused confusion when I used the term "client id" in my earlier comment. I meant to say "primary keys in the client (phone app) database"

Comment: I still don't see the issue here.  The catalog is generated from the MySQL server, not locally (is this a correct assumption?).  Then the records in your app's SQLite database are just temporary until the sync happens.  You should not be driving your app's data off SQLite in this case I beleieve.

Comment: Hmm... ok but when the app is offline, the app needs a copy of all the data (pertaining to that user anyway) as of the last sync. Otherwise it will not work offline. Yes, the data could be outdated if the user hasnt synced in a while, but that's ok. But when he does sync, how to we handle primary key IDs being different in the phone's database and the live server database? Because this is what will likely happen if we use auto-incrementing integer primary keys? Sorry Tim, quite sure I'm maybe missing something here in my train of thought. Im going to re-read your comments again properly now :)

Comment: You see, when the app goes online, and performs a sync, by talking to the Web API, it will tell the Web API "these 3 records are new, please add them to the master database". The Web API will comply, and the master database will insert these 3 new records. But in all likelihood, these 3 new records will get different primary key values (if using int's) so now there is a mismatch between the ID's of the records in the master database as opposed to those on the phone's database

Comment: I'm going to post an answer, you can comment on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having the full details I would suggest the following general workflow:

- a user adds a new product
- this results in a record being written to the local SQLite database
- maintain a column called `sync` which keeps track of whether a local record has been pushed to the server
- note that the products which the app displays is the sum of cached server data and SQLite data which has not yet been synched
- when the app does a sync, it pushes new products first, then marks those SQLite records as having been synched
- when it pulls the latest catalog, it will return the new products with their actual unique IDs as they appear in the remote MySQL database
- if the app goes offline again, then just go back to the first step and do the same thing

The basic idea here is to just focus on keeping one version of the truth as much as possible.  Don't task your app with assigning an ID to a product which the server knows nothing about.  For one thing, would it be meaningful to assign such an ID and then the user decides to delete the product without ever synching?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim. OK, I see where you are coming from, and it makes sense. I just have one question. When the app syncs, the pushing of new records to the master database (via the Web API) should be fine. But what about pushing through edits to existing records? How does the Web API know which record to edit in the master database? And vice versa, if a record has been edited in the master database, how does the app know which corresponding record to update in its local database when it performs the sync? Thanks Tim, I appreciate your input.

Comment: Ok, I realized I might have missed something... Everytime the app syncs, the two databases should be identical, so editing of a record should be fine...

Comment: _Your_ app tells the database which records to update, same as it would tell which new records to insert.  In terms of doing something like getting a product catalog via JSON, your app would just download the entire thing, or if you have some pagination set up, then it would request a certain page.

Comment: Wait...are you trying to mirror the server MySQL table on a SQLite table?  Well, my advice is don't.  Keep one SQLite table for the result of the sync, and the other to store new product additions.

Comment: Aha..... ok, I never thought about doing that... Let me think about it for a minute :)

Comment: I hope you don't mind me picking your brain for a little longer Tim. You seem to be much more clued up (read: "cleverer") than me :) So, when working in offline mode, would the app use the "synced" database to display data? Then, if the user adds, edits or deletes a record, this would be logged into a separate "modifications" database? When the app eventually syncs, everything in the "modifications" database would be synced up to the master database via the Web API. Conversely, any modifications in the master database would be synced down to the "synced" database on the phone. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, in above post, "databases" should be "tables"

Comment: In offline mode it would use the (possibly stale) cached data _plus_ the new products which were added locally, but not yet synched.  That's what the `sync` column could be used for.  When you have synched your local data, you could soft delete those SQLite records.

Comment: In offline mode it would use the (possibly stale) cached data _plus_ the new products which were added locally, but not yet synched.  That's what the `sync` column could be used for.  When you have synched your local data, you could soft delete those SQLite records.

Comment: Ok, I've got it. makes sense. I promise this will be my last question Tim. Regarding syncing from master database, to phone app.... I was thinking about syncing only changes (i.e. the Web API will push to the phone app only records that have changed - added, edited or deleted - since the last sync). I wasn't thinking of pushing through the full catalog.  If I'm not mistaken, your approach requires download of full catalog on every sync?

Comment: Ok, upon further contemplating, I believe your suggested method will work nicely even if the API pushes only modifications to the phone app. Thanks Tim, you've been very helpful! Much appreciated

Comment: If you have follow up questions, you can drop a comment here and/or open a new question.